# How to calculate area of child class from parent class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, geometry

Here are my questions:

1. When I'm printing the **area** of both shapes, I am getting the **correct** area for the **ellipse**, but `0` for the **circles**. Why?
2. I have multiple radii of circle. How can I keep on adding it to area, which was computed by the previous radius? In short, I need to sum the area of all the radii.
3. Whenever I pass the radius of the circle, I also need that the circle area (computed by the radius) should be added to ellipse area as well. How to do that?

This is my current code:

```
public class Ellipse {
    private double area;
    private double axis1;
    private double axis2;

    public Ellipse() {
        area = 0;
    }

    public Ellipse (double axis1, double axis2) {
        this.axis1 = axis1;
        this.axis2 = axis2;
    }

    public void calculateArea() {
        area += axis1 * axis2;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }
}

public class Circle extends Ellipse {
    private double radius;
    private double area;

    public Circle(){
        area = 0;
    }

    public Circle(double radius) {
        super(radius, radius);
    } 

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(10, 20);
        ellipse.calculateArea();
        Circle circle = new Circle(50);
        circle.calculateArea();
        System.out.println("Area of Circle is : " + ellipse.getArea());
        System.out.println("Area of Circle is : " + circle.getArea());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getArea()` method under the class `Circle` you are returning the value of the `area` under `Circle`.

However, you calculate the result in your `area` variable under the `Ellipse` class.

Do this:
Change

```
private double area;
```

to

```
protected double area;
```

and in your `getArea()` method under `Circle` class:

```
public double getArea(){
    return super.area;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*1) When I'm printing the the area of the both shapes, I am getting correct area of ellipse, but I am getting area of circle as zero. Why?*

This is because as *Debanic* states as well, you have declared the *access modifier* of  `Ellipse` as `private`. So when you are `Inheriting`, the `private` 
variable `area` is not going to be inherited by the `Derived` class `Circle`. So what is happening here?

Your `Circle.getArea()` is returning your `Circle` class `area` variable. Which is 0. 
So better you declare `Ellipse` class `area` instance variable as `protected`. And call `super.getArea()` from the `Circle` class. Just how the above answer states. You can put *no access modifier* as well but it would be a problem if your subclass was in a different package.

*2) I have multiple radius of circle. How can I keep on adding to it to area, which was computed by the previous radius (In short, I need to sum the area of all the radiuses).3) Whenever I pass the circle radius, I also need that the circle area (computed by the radius) should be added to ellipse area as well.*

I am not going to write you the whole code but give a hint that will help you out. So, you want to keep on adding the `area` as computed by the `radius` of Circle or `axis1,axis2` of `Ellipse` to one single `area`.

In your code, the hinderance that is being caused from achieving your goal (adding areas to single area everytime) is in the fact that

> Every time you are making a call to the Constructor using `new` keyword You are basically creating a whole new object so in a way the value of area is getting `reset`.

You would like your `area` variable to be common(**shared**) to all the objects. You can do that by declaring it as a `static variable`. 
Then the value of `area` will keep on getting updated every time you operate on it!